# How do I calculate dice roll probabilities while accounting for bonuses and rerolls?

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

I'm trying to learn the easiest way to calculate the percentage chance that a dice roller can meet or exceed a target value under the following rule:

1. Roll a 20-sided die twice.
2. Add $\pm x$ to the **first roll only**.
3. If **either** roll equals or exceeds the target value of $y$, you win.

Ultimately, I'm trying to put an equation into a spreadsheet so that I can just adjust for $x$ and $y$ to quickly discover the probability. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: what is $x$, what is $y$?

Comment: @Masacroso both x and y could be any integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R$ be the random variable corresponding to the outcome of the dice throw.
Let $E_1$ be the event that $R +x \geq y$ for the first throw. Let $E_2$ be the event that $R \geq y$ for the second throw.

It can be derived from the axioms of probability that,

$P(E_1 \cup E_2) = P(E_1)+P(E_2) - P(E_1\cap E_2)$.

By independence of $E_1,E_2$, $P(E_1\cap E_2) = P(E_1)\cdot P(E_2)$, giving us $P(E_1 \cup E_2) = P(E_1)+P(E_2) - P(E_1)\cdot P(E_2)$

In the setting that the 20 sided die is unbiased, $E_1$ occurs when $R$ takes the values from $\{y-x,y-x+1,\dots,20\}$ and $E_2$ occurs when $R$ takes the values from $\{y,y+1,\dots,20\}$. Therefore,
$P(E_1) = \frac{(20-(y-x)+1)}{20}$ and $P(E_2) = \frac{20-y+1}{20}$

Substituting the values will give you: $P(E_1\cup E_2) = \frac{xy-y^2+2y-x+399}{400}$.

In case $x$ and $y$ are not in the range $\{1,\dots,20\}$ or $y-x$ is negative, you need to appropriately bound the values in the above probability.

Comment: Thanks so much for this excellent reply. Just a silly question from me. If x is in the range {1,…,20} but y is not, how would you specifically bound values in the probability?

Comment: ahh ok sorry for not being clear. I meant "$E_1$ occurs when $R$ takes the values from $\{y-x,y-x+1,\dots,20\}$" has to be appropriately bounded below at 0 and above at 20. 

Specifically, if y is not in the range $\{1,\dots,20\}$ then the problem becomes simple as event $E_2$ can never happen. The probability you are looking for is simply $P(E_1)$ and you can check for which values of $R=r$, $r+x\geq y$. 
Illustrating this: say $x = 5, y = 22$, then for $E_1$ to occur, $R \in \{17,18,19,20\}$ for which the probability is $\frac{4}{20}$

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! Thanks for the explanation. In this case, y values would never exceed 20. One last thing I don't quite understand here. In the case where you follow these rules but need to take the LOWER of the two rolls, how does your equation change? I assume E1 and E2 remain the same in that scenario?

Comment: I would suggest a new question for a full explanation on your new question. For min dice roll to be greater than x, you need BOTH rolls to be greater than x. Thus it'll look like $[(20-x+1)/20]^2$